# Showing that the group of $n^{th}$ roots of unity form a group

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I know they are $\{1, \gamma, \gamma^2, ..., \gamma^{n-1}\}$, where $\gamma$ is the primitive n-th root of unity.  To show that this is a group (the four axioms), I did this:

Since $\gamma^i$ is a root, $(\gamma^i)^n = 1$ and similarly since $\gamma^j$ is a root, $(\gamma^j)^n = 1$, thus ($\gamma^i\gamma^j)^n = (\gamma^i)^n(\gamma^j)^n = 1*1 = 1$  The identity element is $1$, the associativity is inherited from the underlying field and for inverses, suppose $\gamma^i$ is a root, then we can divide by it (since we're in a field) and get $\frac{1}{\gamma^i}$ and that raised to the n-th power yields $\frac{1}{1}$ which is just $1$.

Does that seem legit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787981/how-to-prove-the-group-of-roots-of-unity-in-mathbbc-is-a-group.

Comment: It's not the roots of the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial that constitute a group, but the roots of $z^n-1$. For example the second cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_2$ is equal to $z+1$ and not $z^2-1$. Please correct the title.